# how to save a parquet with pandas using same header than hadoop spark parquet?

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, hive, pyarrow

I have a couple of files (csv,..) and am using pandas and pyarrow.table (0.17)
to save it as parquet on disk (parquet version 1.4)

```
colums
id : string
val : string

table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)        
pq.write_table(table, "df.parquet", version='1.0', flavor='spark', write_statistics=True, )
```

However, Hive and Spark does not recognize the parquet version:

```
org.apache.parquet.VersionParser$VersionParseException: Could not parse created_by: parquet-cpp version 1.5.1-SNAPSHOT using format: (.+) version ((.*) )?\(build ?(.*)\)
        at org.apache.parquet.VersionParser.parse(VersionParser.java:112)
        at org.apache.parquet.CorruptStatistics.shouldIgnoreStatistics(CorruptStatistics.java:60)
        at org.apache.parquet.format.converter.ParquetMetadataConverter.fromParquetStatistics(ParquetMetadataConverter.java:263)
```

Just wondering, how to save as "spark parquet" in snappy format,
without using launching spark (ie a bit of overkill).

Metadata seems missing.

EDIT based on Pace Comments:

Issue on older version of parquer, now fixed
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PARQUET-349

Older version of Hive, Spark still have the issue.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-19464

Python Arrow does not provide the parquet version:
https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/4591d76fce2846a29dac33bf01e9ba0337b118e9/python/pyarrow/_parquet.pxd#L360

Comment: It appears you've encountered [PARQUET-349](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PARQUET-349) which was fixed in 2015 before Arrow was even started.  The underlying C++ code does allow this `created_by` field to be customized [source](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/4591d76fce2846a29dac33bf01e9ba0337b118e9/cpp/src/parquet/properties.h#L249) but the python wrapper does not expose this [source](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/4591d76fce2846a29dac33bf01e9ba0337b118e9/python/pyarrow/_parquet.pxd#L360).  Is there any way you can upgrade your Spark parquet version?

Comment: Thanks you vm. In face, this is the Hive parquet reader.  I cannot change the hive version but, is this possible to upload some JARS to fix it >

Answer (score 1):

Besides Pace excellent comments/inights.

A workaround of this issue ist to use fastparquet,
as follow:

```
import fastparquet as fp
df = df.to_pandas()
fp.write('yourdir', df, fixed_text=None,
         compression='SNAPPY', file_scheme='hive')
```